# Translate custom button

Tags: wordpress, translate, poedit, po, mo

I need translated line of custom button in a code, but its not working my solution.

**This is the line in file which I need translate (line 13, name of file: add-to-quote-button.php)**

```
<a href="#" class="<?php echo $class ?>" data-product_id="<?php echo $product_id ?>" data-wp_nonce="<?php echo $wpnonce ?>">Quick Quote</a>
```

**There is my solution which is not working:**

[My solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G0gc.jpg)

**Additional informations:**

*name of my translated file:* yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote-cs_CZ.mo

*file location:* plugins/woocommerce request a quote v1.6.1/templates/add-to-quote-button.php

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.
One is a bit hacky and might get you into trouble if some huge change happens to woocommerce and other one is using CSS.

You could override that file in your child theme if you have one. if not you can do so in your parent theme.

Inside your theme folder create new folder 'woocommerce' and within woocommerce create 'templates' within that folder create file add-to-quote-button.php and copy whole content of the original file into this one and update that text.
Now that should overwrite woocommerce plugin file.

CSS Way would be to find class that's on that button - I'll name it 'someQuoteButton' just so I can give you an example.

```
.someQuoteButton {
   font-size:0;
}
.someQuoteButton:after {
   content: 'Some Content you Want';
   font-size: 16px; // or any you need there
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to translate "*Quick Quote*" text in that line of code?

Try it like this:

```
<a href="#" class="<?php echo $class ?>" data-product_id="<?php echo $product_id ?>" data-wp_nonce="<?php echo $wpnonce ?>"><?php _e( 'Quick Quote', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote') ?></a>
```

Comment: yes, I forgot the php code, you are right, but still not working, so there is still some issue

Comment: I think that missing in your code text domain, but what is it? Name of plugin folder or?

Comment: Have you tried 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' for text-domain?